# Decreasing resolution of Ubuntu in Virtualbox

Tags: 18.04, virtualbox

I am running Ubuntu (18.04 Desktop) inside Virtualbox (6.0) on Mac (10.14.6). After installing Guest Additions, the resolution in the guest OS became too high (2880x1800). When I decrease the resolution in Settings/Devices/Displays, the image gets smaller. I mean, it doesn't fill my laptop's screen anymore.

How can I decrease the resolution without changing the size of the image?

Answer (score 3):

Virtualbox Scaled Mode

1. choose a guest resolution (with guest additions installed, simply resize the window)
2. enable Scale Mode

From your running guest VM window, enter the **View** menu, find **Scale Mode** and enable it.
Or hit <kbd>Host Key</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>
The guest resolution remain fixed, you can resize the guest window, pixels are now scaled.
Exit the scale mode by hitting  <kbd>Host Key</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> again

More information :
https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/UserManual.html#intro-resize-window